# iOS: Force iPhone-only app to run 1x on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, appstore-approval, universal

Well, I got my app rejected from Apple because of this reason:

"iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution"

As soon as run my app, the app shows in 2x mode, and it should be shown at 1x mode. I have tried a lot of things, but I just cant fixe it.

My settings for devices are just iPhone, no universal.
I have tried on iPad retina and no retina, in both the app is shown in 2x mode
I've checked my .plist file, so non iPad related property is in there, nothing.
I'm using a launch image.

This are some of the things that I've tried:

http://goo.gl/on0UHP

http://goo.gl/K2hRZY

So, my question is: how can make my app shown in 1x mode when running on iPad?

Comment: I believe the problem is not the app launching in 2x which the default behavior in the latest OSes. Did Apple give you more information ? I suspect your app does not work well on iPad - no matter the resolution-